# Folium TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, folium

I'm trying to create my first choropleth map with folium.

I have a pandas dataframe which I have successfully used to feed a folium circle map, so I'm pretty confident I don't have an issue with the data content. The below function generated my map just fine.

```python
def plot_cases(cases_date):
    folium_map = folium.Map(location=[40.738, -73.98],
                            zoom_start=1,
                            tiles="CartoDB dark_matter",
                            width='100%')

    #add a circle marker for each row in data    
    for index, row in cases_date.iterrows():

            # generate the popup message that is shown on click.
            popup_text = "Cases: {}<br> Country: {}<br> Province/State: {}"
            popup_text = popup_text.format(row["Cases"], row["Country/Region"], row["Province/State"])
            #radius of circle
            radius = row["Cases"]/1000

            # choose the color of the marker
            if row["Cases"] > 0:
                color="#E37222" # tangerine
            else:  
                color="#0A8A9F" # teal

             # add circle on map
             folium.CircleMarker(location=(row["Lat"],
                                           row["Long"]), 
                                           radius=radius,
                                           color=color,
                                           popup=popup_text,
                                           fill=True).add_to(folium_map)

    return folium_map
```

Now, when I try and generate my choropleth with the same pandas df, the only new concept I introduce is grabbing a world map geoJSON file from a git repo:

```python
#get geoJSON
req = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data/world-countries.json')
geofile = req.json()

#instantiate map and enter choropleth params
m = folium.Map(location=[40.738, -73.98],zoom_start=1,tiles="CartoDB dark_matter",width='100%')

choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data = geofile,
    name='choropleth',
    data=choro_data,
    columns=['Country/Region', 'Cases'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Cases',
    highlight=True,
    line_color='black'
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(m)

m
```

The above choropleth code generates the following traceback:

```python
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-27efeb8f5173> in <module>
     12     legend_name='Cases',
     13     highlight=True,
---> 14     line_color='black'
     15 ).add_to(m)
     16 

~/cases/map/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1076         if color_data is not None and key_on is not None:
   1077             real_values = np.array(list(color_data.values()))
-> 1078             real_values = real_values[~np.isnan(real_values)]
   1079             _, bin_edges = np.histogram(real_values, bins=bins)
   1080 

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

hpaulj suggested there is a problem with the json.  You can view the json at the source, but I also pulled out a sample from `print(geofile)`:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Afghanistan"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              61.210817,
              35.650072
            ],
            [
              62.230651,
              35.270664
            ],
            [
              62.984662,
              35.404041
            ],
            [
              63.193538,
              35.857166
            ],
            [
              63.982896,
              36.007957
            ],
            [
              64.546479,
              36.312073
            ],
            [
              64.746105,
              37.111818
            ],
            [
              65.588948,
              37.305217
            ],
            [
              65.745631,
              37.661164
            ],
            [
              66.217385,
              37.39379
            ],
            [
              66.518607,
              37.362784
            ],
            [
              67.075782,
              37.356144
            ],
            [
              67.83,
              37.144994
            ],
            [
              68.135562,
              37.023115
            ],
            [
              68.859446,
              37.344336
            ],
            [
              69.196273,
              37.151144
            ],
            [
              69.518785,
              37.608997
            ],
            [
              70.116578,
              37.588223
            ],
            [
              70.270574,
              37.735165
            ],
            [
              70.376304,
              38.138396
            ],
            [
              70.806821,
              38.486282
            ],
            [
              71.348131,
              38.258905
            ],
            [
              71.239404,
              37.953265
            ],
            [
              71.541918,
              37.905774
            ],
            [
              71.448693,
              37.065645
            ],
            [
              71.844638,
              36.738171
            ],
            [
              72.193041,
              36.948288
            ],
            [
              72.63689,
              37.047558
            ],
            [
              73.260056,
              37.495257
            ],
            [
              73.948696,
              37.421566
            ],
            [
              74.980002,
              37.41999
            ],
            [
              75.158028,
              37.133031
            ],
            [
              74.575893,
              37.020841
            ],
            [
              74.067552,
              36.836176
            ],
            [
              72.920025,
              36.720007
            ],
            [
              71.846292,
              36.509942
            ],
            [
              71.262348,
              36.074388
            ],
            [
              71.498768,
              35.650563
            ],
            [
              71.613076,
              35.153203
            ],
            [
              71.115019,
              34.733126
            ],
            [
              71.156773,
              34.348911
            ],
            [
              70.881803,
              33.988856
            ],
            [
              69.930543,
              34.02012
            ],
            [
              70.323594,
              33.358533
            ],
            [
              69.687147,
              33.105499
            ],
            [
              69.262522,
              32.501944
            ],
            [
              69.317764,
              31.901412
            ],
            [
              68.926677,
              31.620189
            ],
            [
              68.556932,
              31.71331
            ],
            [
              67.792689,
              31.58293
            ],
            [
              67.683394,
              31.303154
            ],
            [
              66.938891,
              31.304911
            ],
            [
              66.381458,
              30.738899
            ],
            [
              66.346473,
              29.887943
            ],
            [
              65.046862,
              29.472181
            ],
            [
              64.350419,
              29.560031
            ],
            [
              64.148002,
              29.340819
            ],
            [
              63.550261,
              29.468331
            ],
            [
              62.549857,
              29.318572
            ],
            [
              60.874248,
              29.829239
            ],
            [
              61.781222,
              30.73585
            ],
            [
              61.699314,
              31.379506
            ],
            [
              60.941945,
              31.548075
            ],
            [
              60.863655,
              32.18292
            ],
            [
              60.536078,
              32.981269
            ],
            [
              60.9637,
              33.528832
            ],
            [
              60.52843,
              33.676446
            ],
            [
              60.803193,
              34.404102
            ],
            [
              61.210817,
              35.650072
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "AFG"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Apparently the `geofile` is not the right type or format for this use.  At the error it is checking a numpy array for `nan` a float number.

Comment: Added sample of json in edit to original post.  You can also view raw by following the github url in post.  I'm not seeing anything that doesn't look right from a json perspective.

Comment: Does `folium` say it can work directly from the json format?

Comment: Yea, per documenation: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.features   Parameters
geo_data (string/object) – URL, file path, or data (json, dict, geopandas, etc) to your GeoJSON geometries

Comment: Ok - looks as if the json was a red herring. Code further up in my script was actually feeding the wrong dataframe to `data=choro_data` so effectively the folium was receiving malformed data set info and throwing the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - looks as if the json was a red herring. Code further up in my script was actually feeding the wrong dataframe to `data=choro_data` so effectively the folium was receiving malformed data set info and throwing the errors.

Comment: That was quick.